# Trying to get the percentage of male/female who have applied to a job with an age range

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry about the confusing title, what I am trying to achieve is, getting the total applications for a job via the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `applications` (
  `application_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `application_user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `application_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `application_job` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `application_status` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'pending',
  `application_enabled` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `application_resume` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `application_description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`application_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

to get their ages, I am left joining `user_personal_information` on to `application_user` because they're the user who has applied to a job. My query:

```
SELECT count(*) as total,
       user_gender as gender,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_birthdate, CURDATE()) AS age,
       application_date
FROM applications
LEFT JOIN user_personal_information
    ON user_personal_information_user = application_user
WHERE application_job = ?
```

My user's table with `user_gender` which can equal to `male` / `female` and `user_birthdate` which in the above statement I am converting it to an age.

I am trying to group all the applications with an age range of for example:

```
16 - 21
22 - 30
31 - 45
45 - 64
65+
```

And the male and female percentages for that age. To use for a datachart that needs data like so:

```
 "dataProvider": [
 {
   "age": "85+",
   "male": 25, //
   "female": 25
 }, {
   "age": "80-54",
   "male": 25,//percentage
   "female": 25//percentage
}]
```

So from the above, there's 25 % of males have applied aged 85 and older, and 25% of females. You get the gist, so that's how I am trying to get my select statement to work.

which will create a chart like so:

[image]

So just to clarify, I want to count the total applications and work out the percentage of applications based on gender and age group. How can I do this with the select statement above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of nested group-by subqueries can do it for you. Note that the percentage calculated is gender specific:

```
select a.age, a.gender, a.cnt, 100*a.cnt/b.sm as percentage from
    (
        SELECT user_gender as gender,
               TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_birthdate, CURDATE()) AS age,
               count(*) as cnt,
        FROM applications
        LEFT JOIN user_personal_information
        ON user_personal_information_user = application_user
        WHERE application_job = ?
        GROUP BY user_gender, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_birthdate, CURDATE())
    ) a,
    (
        SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_birthdate, CURDATE()) AS age,
               count(*) as sm
        FROM applications
        LEFT JOIN user_personal_information
        ON user_personal_information_user = application_user
        WHERE application_job = ?
        GROUP BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_birthdate, CURDATE())
    ) b
    where a.age = b.age;
```

If you are looking for a percentage specific to total applications, you need something like:

```
select a.age, 
       a.gender, 
       a.cnt, 
100*a.cnt/(
            select count(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_birthdate, CURDATE()))
            from
            applications 
            LEFT JOIN user_personal_information
            ON user_personal_information_user = application_user
            WHERE application_job = ?
         ) as percentage 
from
    (
        SELECT user_gender as gender,
               TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_birthdate, CURDATE()) AS age,
               count(*) as cnt,
        FROM applications
        LEFT JOIN user_personal_information
        ON user_personal_information_user = application_user
        WHERE application_job = ?
        GROUP BY user_gender, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_birthdate, CURDATE())
    ) a;
```

Comment: Sorry I was trying to get the percentage too and display the age range i.e (40-50)

Comment: need to use a `case when` statement on the calculated age to limit them to groups (e.g. 16-21 etc.) & then group by that as well as gender

Comment: I chose to nest two group by's and query on the spoils of their join. I think it'll work.

Comment: I am getting an error: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'a
       (
           SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, user_birthdate, CURDATE()) AS' at line 16 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\job\application\model\AnalyticModel.php</b> on line <b>71</b><br />

Comment: Well, close parantheses were missing after `CURDATE()`. Edited!

Comment: I've accepted as best answer. I really appreciate  the help :) Have a great day, bud!

Comment: Edit, is there anyway I can get the percentage of all the applications rather than male female? i.e because this works the percentage for the age group and not in total? thnks

Comment: Sure, that I think is a simpler problem. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
select 
 sum(case when age between 16 and 21 and gender='male' then 1 end) as '[Male 16-21]',
 sum(case when age between 16 and 21 and gender='female' then 1 end) as 'Female [16-21]',
 sum(case when age between 22 and 30 and gender='male' then 1 end) as '[Male 22-30]',
 sum(case when age between 22 and 30 and gender='female' then 1 end) as '[Female 22-30]',
 sum(case when age between 31 and 45 and gender='male' then 1 end) as '[Male 31-45]',
 sum(case when age between 31 and 45 and gender='female' then 1 end) as '[Female 31-45]',
 sum(case when age between 46 and 64 and gender='male' then 1 end) as '[Male 46-64]',
 sum(case when age between 46 and 64 and gender='female' then 1 end) as '[Female 46-64]',
 sum(case when age > 64              and gender='male' then 1 end) as '[Male Over 64]',
 sum(case when age > 64              and gender='female' then 1 end) as '[Female Over 64]',
 sum(case when 1=1                   and gender='female' then 1 end) as '[Male TOTAL]',
 sum(case when 1=1                   and gender='male' then 1 end) as '[Female TOTAL]'

FROM applications
```